# cloudfront/s3 not using cache-control

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am uploading an image to S3. Here are the header/request:

```
PUT /d899a0475f39e4a1d8c4b2af540d0820.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHRUBWYK7YNNWSLQ&Expires=1376548390&Signature=uP677w4lNA81USKByuJwU0FmUuE%3D&Cache-Control:%20max-age=229000 HTTP/1.1
Host: test199801672.s3.amazonaws.com
Content-Length: 436983
Content-Type: image/png
```

I am passing in `Cache-Control: max-age=229000`

I get a 200 OK response and the image is uploaded, but for some reason the `Cache-Control` value isn't read. When downloading the image, I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 436983
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 05:33:15 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 05:33:11 GMT
ETag: "dbb3afa053cfc18e45f1d8c7ef8ddfd4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Via: 1.0 9dd1962ecf68cae08454f386dd1975c1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: anyUV_WtyIdEjDrRsrsWc5l9WGIVW0AnIjNn7b_g_EgS7rlP0rxoAw==
```

No `Cache-Control` header in response. `X-Cache` says: `Miss from cloudfront`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your cache behaviour setting of Cloudfront distribution that the object caching is ticked at "Use Origin Cache Headers"?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

I have set the Cache-Control max-age=3600 header for each of my files in S3 using the control panel under metadata. (API can do this)

My CloudFront is has the Behavior Object Caching = Use Origin Cache Headers.

My website's header responses now show the Cache-Control header I set in S3.

(of course had to wait cloud front to invalidate its existing verison of those files, I helped this along with CloudFront invalidation on those files)

Comment: Did you use a "custom origin" or a "s3-origin"?

Answer (score 0):

When the img resource is requested via address bar, Chrome & Opera sends Cache-Control=0 in Request header & Safari send Cache=No. Because of this browser does not pick up images from cache.

Firefox does not send such headers.

But when same url is requested via image src tag, all browsers respect cache control & in their request above header is never sent